# unable to configure django url path

Tags: django-views, django-urls

i cant guess the proper path for the views to be added within project urls ?
im using django =2.2.6

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN6JS.png "the error image"

this is the code within, **project_two/urls.py**:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path,include

 urlpatterns = [
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('appTwo/', include('appTwo.urls'))
                path('appTwo/views/', views.users, name='users')
              ]
```

the output error :

```
File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "E:\stuff\web dev\django_projects\project_two\project_two\urls.py", line 23
path('appTwo/views/', views.users, name='users')
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please paste your code in the question or insert the image here, and not paste the link? It's getting hard sometimes when the links get broken.

Comment: will this do i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change your code like this.

1. project_two/urls.py

   urlpatterns = [
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
               path('appTwo/', include('appTwo.urls')),
   ]
2. project_two/appTwo/urls.py

   urlpatterns = [
               path('views/', views.users, name='users'),
   ]

Comment: i figured it out ,i had forgot to import the views apparently into the project_two/appTwo/urls.py: from appTwo import views

Answer (score 0):

Add comma at the end of the previous line, and remove the one you have in that line.

So your code must look like this

```
urlPatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('appTwo/', include('appTwo,urls')),
   path('appTwo/views/', views.users, name='users')
]
```

Comment: are you sure about the comma? because in your code you pasted it is still missing

Comment: i cant add the error code like u did in the comment box

Comment: File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appTwo,urls'

Comment: well now this is a different problem, isn't it?

Comment: Can u  help me with both ?

Comment: I'm not a Django expert unfortunately. Try editing your question though for other users to be able  to identify the problem easily.

Comment: Ok understood ,well as for adding  'code' comments within the chat how do i do that ?

Comment: I recommend you not doing that. It is better to edit the question and insert code snippetes there